# How to use JScript to change text of Textbox and Label

Tags: .net, javascript

Hi I am a newbie of .net trying to use the JScript to change the text of Textbox and label and it seems does not work.

the following is my function

```
function Settxext(XTtitle, YTtitle, iValue) {

    document.getElementById("MainContent_lblFactorX").text = XTtitle;
    document.getElementById("MainContent_lblFactorY").text = YTtitle;
    document.getElementById("MainContent_txBonus").text = iValue;

}
```

when I start debugging the id name of my windows item been add MainContent_ as prefix, also, it does not work as I expect, what should I do to fix this problem, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The only foreseeable problem in your code is the use of the `text` property, which should actually be `value`. At least, that's the case if you want to write cross-platform JavaScript. Other than that, everything seems just fine.

Answer (score 0):

That's how it should look like:

```
document.getElementById("<%=lblFactorX.ClientID%>").innerHTML = XTtitle;
document.getElementById("<%=lblFactorY.ClientID%>").innerHTML = YTtitle;
document.getElementById("<%=txBonus.ClientID%>").value = iValue;
```

This assumes `lblFactorX` and `lblFactorY` are Labels and `txBonus` is Textbox.

Comment: @Time cheers, feel free to accept the answer then as well as the answer to your other question. :)